# Cannot Connect to SQL Server Express 2014 from java

Tags: sql-server

I've been at this for a few days now and the error stays the same.

> Login failed for user". ClientConnectionId

I have connected to the database successfully, but the "login failed for user" which doesn't make sense because the username is "sa" and the password "tazmo1", the same as the login and password was when installed SQL Server Express. This is what i have so far...

```
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    String userName = "sa";
    String password = "tazmo1";
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=AdventureWorks2012;integratedSecurity=true";
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
```

I have also used

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url)
```

and

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=AdventureWorks2012;integratedSecurity=true")
```

even used

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=AdventureWorks2012,user="sa",password="tazmo1");`
```

I've been reading numerous stackoverflow forums that point me to the same thing, make sure the TCP/IP dynamic ports are removed add 1433 to all the TCP/IP Port. I have done all that, and it connect then stops working as the "login failed". Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: Also the firewalls are disabled and all the TCP ports are 1433, Help me please!

Comment: `"jdbc:sqlserver://MYPC\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=MYDB";`

Comment: same thing, login failed for user. I'm the sa of the database and it is still failing, I don't understand this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have IntegratedSecurity set to true.  That will use your Windows Auth credentials, even if you are passing in the SQL Auth credentials.

Comment: then you're tell me I dont need the integratedSecurity to true, just take it out?

Comment: @ChrisEspi that depends - do you want to use Windows integrated security, or SQL authentication? If you want SQL Auth, then set `IntegratedSecurity` to `false` or remove it entirely.

Comment: I set it to do both...ill try to set it to false.

Comment: All of these have failed...
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
   String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=AdventureWorks2012;user=sa;password=tazmo1";
   String url2 = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;user=sa;password=tazmo1";
   String url4 ="jdbc:sqlserver://;servername=sqlexpress;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationS‌​cheme=JavaKerberos";
   String url5 ="jdbc:sqlserver://hahaha\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=AdventureWorks2012";
   String url3 = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;user=sa;password=tazmo1";
   con = DriverManager.getConnection(url5);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: you are using integratedSecurity=True which means you are using microsoft's standard instead of yours, set it to false and it will use YOUR username and password. You could also try this, instead of integratedsecurity:    "databaseName=AdventureWorks;user=MyUserName;password=*****;";

Comment: I've tried but thank you what would be the next step?

Comment: Have you deleted the variables     String userName = "sa";
    String password = "tazmo1" before trying it on the URL?


This is what I would use. 
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" +
   "databaseName=AdventureWorks2012;user=sa;password=tazmo1;";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);